# add additional custom auto complete to oh-my-zsh plugins

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I recently migrated to oh-my-zsh and would like to add additional method besides the default plugin provided auto complete methods. is there a way I can do it? I know I can use alias but that will not allow to have space in the middle. More over I am looking for an auto complete. Example of what I want to achieve is to add a `build` function which can be displayed on tab for `mvn` command so that it will be listed with auto completed.

Comment: This would be better suited to [Unix & Linux StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com) since it isn't really about programming.

Comment: Is it not a programming? since we code it to add additional function/method? @Esther

Comment: do you have some code you have a question about? If so, post that and edit your question. As it is I don't see the programming question. "how to achieve x feature with y software" isn't a programming question. The U&L people would be happy to answer that, though.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Is there a way I can move this question to U&L? or should I close it here and create a new one there? @Esther

Comment: since it has no answers/etc here, just closing and opening a new one there is best.

Answer (score 1):

For autocomplete (from history) you can use the zsh-autosuggestion.
Basically you just clone the git repository to `.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/` and add `zsh-autosuggestions` to your plugins list.
Read more here: https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions/blob/master/INSTALL.md

Side note is that the built-in `mvn` plugin gives great autocomplete for commands related to maven.
To install you just add `mvn` to your list of plugins and `omz reload`
Then when you type `mvn [tab][tab]` you get all the supported commands related to mvn. Pretty handy.

I use both plugins. So when typing `mvn` i get the "previous" mvn command greyed out in the shell so i can run it by typing right-arrow, or select history by using up and down arrow. If continuing to type it will use the mvn plugin to autocomplete commands.

To add additional targets for the mvn plugins, you can edit the plugin yourself.
https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/master/plugins/mvn/mvn.plugin.zsh#L122

Simply add your target text to the `reply` statement.

Comment: I am not looking for auto complete from the history. I already added the maven plugin. I want to have additional function, which is not shipped by maven plugin. As I mentioned, I want to extend maven to have a function `build` which does some additional tasks

Comment: Updated answer. To add targets you can edit the plugin and insert them directly.